# Keep the initial animation for the other slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an animation, in which several slides are shown with their respective title. My problem is to generate the same initial animation on the other slides. The first time it is executed, the animation of the title appears from the left, but in the other slides does not work. I want the animation of the title that can be seen the first time it runs, always stay on the other slides. How can I do it?

I am using wow.js for animate the title (animation from left) and slick.js for the slides.

This is my project:

https://jsfiddle.net/vvj2n4g7/

```
new WOW().init();  //http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/  
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sliderMain').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,

    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000 //5000
  });
  $('.sliderSidebar').slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: false,
    centerMode: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    vertical: true,
    arrows: false
  });
  $('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
    if (vid.length > 0) {
      $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause');
      $(vid).get(0).play();
    }

  });

  var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    videos[i].addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
  }

  function myHandler(e) {
    console.log('Video Complete')
    $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPlay');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem adding a "beforeChange" in order to set display to none, and set display to block in your afterChange event, your code should look like this:

```js
$('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
    if (vid.length > 0) {
        $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause');
        $(vid).get(0).play();
    }
    //After change set it to block
    $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "block");
});

//Add this event handler
$('.sliderMain').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
    //Defore change set it to none
    $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "none");
});
```

Your complete JQuery should look like this:

```js
new WOW().init();  //http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sliderMain').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,

      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 4000 //5000
    });

    $('.sliderSidebar').slick({
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      centerMode: false,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      vertical: true,
      arrows: false
    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        var vid = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]).find('video');
        if (vid.length > 0) {
            $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPause');
            $(vid).get(0).play();
        }
        //After change set it to block
        $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "block");
    });

    $('.sliderMain').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        //Defore change set it to none
        $('.contenedor_nombre_proyecto').css("display", "none");
    });

    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    }

    function myHandler(e) {
        console.log('Video Complete')
        $('.sliderMain').slick('slickPlay');
    }
});
```